# After filtering the listview items, the item does not open the corresponding activity

Tags: java, android, listview, search, searchview

I have a listview and the items corresponds to different activities..after searching for the required item and clicking on it the item at the position 0 gets opened instead of the activity corresponding to the item...
EG: item1
    item2
    item3
search:item3, after clicking on the searched item3
problem:it will open the activity corresponding to item1.

here's my code:

```
package com.example.acer.aartisangrah;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class first extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
private ListView listView;

private String[] names = {"प्रार्थना", "सुखकर्ता दु:खहर्ता", "गजानना श्रीगणराया", "येई हो विठ्ठले", "लवथवती विक्राळा", "दुर्गे दुर्घट भारी", "आरती ज्ञानराजा",
        "हे भोळ्या शंकरा", "ओवाळू", "मंगेशा महारूद्रा", "आला गणराया", "शेंदुर लाल चढायो", "एकदंता", "कर्पूर गौरा", "हे गजवधना", "प्रथमेश्वरा", "जयदेवा हे  साईनाथा",
        "श्री सत्यनारायणाची आरती", "श्री महालक्ष्मीची आरती", "ॐ जय लक्ष्मी माता", "आरती संतोषी माता की", "धन्य धन्य हो प्रदक्षिणा", "सुखंकर्ता की दु:खहर्ता",
        "ॐ जय जगदीश", "हे गौरी गजानन", "घालीन लोटांगण"};
private int imageid[] = {R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji, R.drawable.ganeshaji};
int textlength=0;
ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(names,imageid));
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()

    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after)
        {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count)
        {   textlength = editText.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();
            image_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
            {
                if (textlength <= names[i].length())
                {
                    if (editText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) names[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
                    {
                        text_sort.add(names[i]);
                        image_sort.add(imageid[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, image_sort));
        }

    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), akalp.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Sukharta.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), gajananashriganraya.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), yehihovittale.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), lavathavthi.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), durgedurgat.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 6) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nyanraja.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 7) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), bolya.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 8) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), vovalo.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 9) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), mangesha.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 10) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), alaganraya.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 11) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), shendorlal.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 12) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ekdanta.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 13) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), karpurgaura.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 14) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), heygajavadana.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 15) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), prathmeshvara.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 16) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), sainatha.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 17) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), satyanarayan.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 18) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), jaidevijaidevi.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 19) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),omjaimahalakshmi.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 20) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), maitohaarti.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 21) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), danyadanyaho.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 22) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), sukhartakidukharta.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 23) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), omjaijagdish.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 24) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), heygaurigajanana.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
            if (position == 25) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ghalinlotangan.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });

}
class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    String[] data_text;
    int[] data_image;
    MyCustomAdapter()
    {

    }

    MyCustomAdapter(String[] names, int[] imageid)
    {
        data_text = names;
        data_image = imageid;
    }
    MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> imageid)
    {
        data_text = new String[names.size()];
        data_image = new int[imageid.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++)
        {
            data_text[i] = names.get(i);
            data_image[i] = imageid.get(i);
        }
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return data_text.length;
    }
    public String getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textview.setText(data_text[position]);
        imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);
        return (row);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: send code for onclick method

Comment: check now @GaneshKarewad

Comment: @Devk as you are checking position therefore it will move according to position not according to your filter view so you need to get either class and set id in it and check id or you can do easy thing as get string from position and then check it in string and call activity..

Comment: @Vickyexpert could you please write some brief code and tell me where to put...im new to this...

Comment: @Devk check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code and create one method for new screen as I have shown below,

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        String strSelectedString = tv.getText().toString();
        for(int selectedPosition = 0; selectedPosition  < names.lenght; selectedPosition++)
        {
            if(names[selectedPosition].equalsIgnoreCase(strSelectedString))
            {
                moveToNextActivity(selectedPosition);
                break;
            }
        }    

        }
    });

    public void moveToNextActivity(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), akalp.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        if (position == 1) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Sukharta.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        if (position == 2) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), gajananashriganraya.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 3) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), yehihovittale.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), lavathavthi.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 5) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), durgedurgat.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 6) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nyanraja.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 7) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), bolya.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 8) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), vovalo.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 9) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), mangesha.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 10) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), alaganraya.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 11) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), shendorlal.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 12) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ekdanta.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 13) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), karpurgaura.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 14) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), heygajavadana.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 15) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), prathmeshvara.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 16) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), sainatha.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 17) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), satyanarayan.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 18) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), jaidevijaidevi.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 19) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),omjaimahalakshmi.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 20) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), maitohaarti.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 21) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), danyadanyaho.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 22) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), sukhartakidukharta.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 23) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), omjaijagdish.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 24) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), heygaurigajanana.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
        if (position == 25) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ghalinlotangan.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice answer sir but it will work only if user search for full value, if user enters partial name then it will not work

Comment: it will work as it is comparing the value of list view not the edittext value and also it is checking in main array so whatever user will input it will show result according to selected position of listview

Comment: @Vickyexpert What do you mean by method for new screen

Comment: @Vickyexpert....that solved my problem....but now the problem is after making the search and pressing back button it doesnt take me to the original listview...instead i have to clear the contents of the editText....
Thanks for your time and help...please help me to resolve this issue also

Comment: It directly exits the app....if there is any content in the edittext....if there is any content and back button is pressed then it should take me to the starting listview....thats all

Comment: @Devk for that you need to override onBackPressed method and there check if edittext has text then clear it and set original adapter otherwise perform back click

Comment: you can accept this answer if it help you in resolve your problem

Comment: @Override Public void onBackPressed(){ if(editText != null){editText.setText(""); listView.setSelection(0); else finish();}

Comment: This code takes me to the main listview clearing the contents of editText....but after that pressing back button it doesn't exit the app....

Comment: I will accept the answer after this is resolved...thanks in advance....

Comment: You have put wrong condition, edittext will never be null as you have assign resource, write below condition it will work

Comment: @Override Public void onBackPressed(){ if(editText.getText().toString().length > 0){editText.setText(""); listView.setSelection(0); else finish();}

Comment: Thanks @Vickeyexpert.....bdw for that filtering thing....I dont want it to check from the initial position....if whatever typed in the edit text is matched with the list view item it should show that as result.....

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing here is starting a new activity based on position of listelement clicked. what happens when user search for perticular elmement position will get changed and your program will start an activity based on position of original listview. instead of using if(position == x) use something else that will remain same even if your list view changes. you can get element details by using code

```
  Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
  ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
  String name =obj_itemDetails.getName();
```

and then use name to compare before starting new activity like

```
if(name.equals(sukharta)){
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Sukharta.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
```

i hope this will help. samajal nahi tar parat wichara

Comment: even if the user types सु.....the user should be shown the items containing that letter in its starting positiion...

Comment: in one line you cant invoke activity by checking position, it will work if user do not search. you have to check with other properties like name or whatever you can.

Comment: after searching it has to show the results and then the user can open whichever item he wants from the search results....

Comment: try to use if(id==x) instaead of if(position==x) it will work

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
 ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
 String name =obj_itemDetails.getName();
 if(name.equals(sukharta)){
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Sukharta.class);
 startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
 }
```